# Multiple user interafce in xcode 6 [swift] with UISegmentedcontrol

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm starting to develop apps in Xcode 6 with swift. It's my first experience with programming. 
I'm developing an app that needs to have more than one user interface, and I want to switch between them with a segmented control. Can anybody tell me how to do it? Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using a `UITabBarController`?  It's designed for switching between UIs.

Comment: Oh, that's great, I didn't that it existed. Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example from one of my projects with an IBAction from the UISegmentedControl using a switch statement for control flow.   It was a calculator app.  Don't worry about the specific logic.  But you can see how to do what you asked.  Use each case of the switch statement to segue to a different view.

```
 @IBAction func dateSegmentedControl(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    oneDayArray = []
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex
        {
    case 0:
        segmentedControlCase = "All"
        oneDayArray = historyGameData
        self.historyViewTable.reloadData()
        break
    case 1:
        segmentedControlCase = "+"
        historyArray(historySign: segmentedControlCase)
    case 2:
        segmentedControlCase = "-"
        historyArray(historySign: segmentedControlCase)
    case 3:
        segmentedControlCase = "x"
        historyArray(historySign: segmentedControlCase)
    case 4:
        segmentedControlCase = "÷"
        historyArray(historySign: segmentedControlCase)
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code snippet for creating the simple uisegmentedcontrol in ios

```
   @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        textLabel.text = "First Segment Selected";
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func segmentedControlAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        
        if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
        {
            textLabel.text = "First Segment Selected";
        }
        else if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
        {
            textLabel.text = "Second Segment Selected";
        }
        else if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2)
        {
            textLabel.text = "Third Segment Selected";
        }
    }
```

if need detail explanation please refer the below link.

https://sourcefreeze.com/uisegmentedcontrol-example-using-swift-in-ios/